SQL Query for Replacing the First Non-Zero Digit in History Code with Sequential Values Based on Date-Based Conditions
I’m working on a SQL query that includes a nested select statement. I need to modify it so that the first non-zero value from the right in a "history code" is replaced with a sequence of consecutive numbers, based on certain conditions.
For example, if the history code is 0302230, I want to transform it into 0302232100. In this example, the 3 (which is the first non-zero value from the right) is replaced with 3210, resulting in 03022(3210)0.
The history code logic depends on conditions involving two dates: paidAt and deadlineDate.
transforming the first non-zero occurrence in the history code depending on its value. Here’s a summary of the logic:
If the first non-zero digit from the right is 1, replace it with 10.
If it's 2, replace it with 210.
If it's 3, replace it with 3210, and so on up to:
If it's 6, replace it with 6543210.
If it's W, replace it W6543210.
and append the rest of the history code
Below is the SQL code I’m currently working with:

SELECT

GROUP_CONCAT(

CASE

WHEN i.paidAt IS NULL

AND DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < CURDATE()

AND i.dueDate = (

SELECT MIN(i2.dueDate)

FROM installment i2

WHERE i2.contractId = i.contractId

AND i2.paidAt IS NULL

AND DATE_ADD(i2.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) < CURDATE()

LIMIT 1

)

THEN

CASE

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) <= 0 THEN '0'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 1 AND 29 THEN '1'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '2'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '3'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 90 AND 119 THEN '4'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 120 AND 149 THEN '5'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 150 AND 179 THEN '6'

WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) >= 180 THEN 'W'

END

ELSE

CASE

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) <= 0 THEN '0'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 1 AND 29 THEN '1'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 30 AND 59 THEN '2'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN '3'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 90 AND 119 THEN '4'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 120 AND 149 THEN '5'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) BETWEEN 150 AND 179 THEN '6'

WHEN DATEDIFF(i.paidAt, DATE_ADD(i.deadlineDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)) >= 180 THEN 'W'

END

END ORDER BY i.dueDate DESC SEPARATOR ''

)

FROM installment i

WHERE i.contractId = [c.id](http://c.id/)

) AS 'Payment History Status Code',


Could someone help me implement the logic to correctly replace only the first non-zero value from the right in the history code?
                           r  


Please provide the create table command and some sample input data, at least as text, better as insert commands. It's much easier that you provide that information than all people who want to try out possible solutions must create it.

This is never going to be easy in SQL, but it would be easy in a scripting language like Python.

Your code includes a lot of conditions not described in the question. Can we disregard the date conditions? If not, you need to describe that logic too. Please also providr sample data and expected output.

The first non zero digit from the right can never be 7,8,9? Also what use is this?

The other thing I was wondering about is what happens when you get to W6543210 and run the code again, does this change? or not?

Why not accept the answer and upvote then?

Do you have REGEXP_INSTR?:
SELECT id, Historycode, char_length(HistoryCode),TargetCharPos,
   case substring(HistoryCode, TargetCharPos , 1)
         when '0' then HistoryCode
         else concat(
                left(HistoryCode, TargetCharPos-1),
                case substring(HistoryCode, TargetCharPos , 1)
                  when '1' then '10'
                  when '2' then '210'
                  when '3' then '3210'
                  when '6' then '6543210'
                end,
                substring(HistoryCode,TargetCharPos+1)
            )
           end as NewHistoryCode
from ( SELECT id, Historycode, REGEXP_INSTR(HistoryCode, '[^0]0*$') as TargetCharPos FROM Tbl
      ) Step1

We find the position of the last non-zero character position in the subquery and then work-out the replacement in the main query.
You might be able to use REGEXP_REPLACE to simplify but I haven't tried it.
If you don't have REGEXP* functions you can use:
char_length(rtrim(replace(HistoryCode, '0', ' '))) as TargetCharPos

Relying on rtrim handling only rightmost spaces. If your last non-zero character can be a 'space' char, then you need to replace them with something else, first.

this worked!! thank you so much!!
